# CSS to display no-wrap DIVs in a grid with automatic number of columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Say, if I want to display a group of non-wrapping `div`'s in a grid, all aligned to the left, so that the number of columns is determined automatically based on the browser's window width.

Can I do it with CSS?

Here's a sketch to show this:

[image]

I was able to find the following `grid` CSS property, but the issue is that it wants me to specify minimum width of an individual cell, or `8em` in my example below, which defeats the purpose, as I don't know how wide each cell is.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell"> ...</div>
  <div class="cell"> .......... </div>
  ...
  <div class="cell"> ..... </div>
</div>


.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8em, 1fr));
}

.cell{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px 0.5em 1px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```